# 'Preclude' vs 'Exclude' vs 'Prevent'

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

I'm trying to really understand how the word *preclude* differs from either *exclude* or *include.* Merriam Webster defines preclude as

> to make impossible by necessary consequence : rule out in advance

Which sounds a lot like either *prevent* or *exclude.* Does *prevent* block a future action from happening, while *preclude* eliminates the possibility of that action altogether?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are correct that there is some overlap between "preclude" and both "prevent" and "exclude". They may sometimes be almost interchangeable, but certainly not always.

I would say that *preclude* is used to indicate that one event or circumstance prevents another event or circumstance from happening. It indicates *cause and effect*.

You've referred to the definition in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preclude), but did you also look at the usage examples that it gives:

> She suffered an injury that precluded the possibility of an athletic career.

i.e. The injury *prevented her from pursuing* an athletic career.
She couldn't pursue an athletic career *because of* the injury.

> Bad weather precluded any further attempts to reach the summit.

i.e. The bad weather *prevented them from making* any further attempts to reach the summit.
They couldn't make any further attempts to reach the summit *because of* the bad weather.

> The secret nature of his work precluded official recognition. (Example from [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/preclude?q=preclude))

i.e. His work could not be officially recognised *because* it was secret.

One [dictionary definition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preclude) seems quite explanatory:

> Remove the possibility of; rule out; prevent or exclude; to make impossible.

and, helpfully, gives an example of *not precluding*:

> It has been raining for days, but that doesn’t preclude the possibility that the skies will clear by this afternoon!

i.e. it could still be a clear afternoon *even though* it has been raining for days.
Using *not preclude* in this fashion is also fairly common.

So:

- Yes, it does mean "prevent", but the word is used in a slightly different way.
- Yes, it does mean "exclude", but "exclude" does not carry the implication of *cause and effect*.

Comment: I'm still not satisfied on the distinction between "prevent" and "preclude". The examples given here could all use "prevent" instead and they'd mean the same thing. As far as I can tell, the main reason to use "preclude" is when you want to sound fancy or sophisticated. Is there more to it than this?